# Loop through entire file python

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I've put together this piece of code:

```
flux =[31.,29,27.,25.]
F=[]
with open("results.rdx", "r") as file1:
for line in enumerate(file1):   
    f_list = [float(i) for line in file1 for i in line.split(',') if 
    i.strip()]
    F = f_list[7:11]
    with open("results.txt", "a+") as file2:
            file2.write(str(chisqfunc(flux,F)))
            file2.write("\n")
```

And my input file looks like this:

```
5.0, 1000.0, 100000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408, 
1.053E-09, 1.839E-09, 1.632E-10, 1.959E-12, 4.109, 3.683, 3.586, 3.650 
5.0, 1000.0, 500000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408, 
4.873E-09, 8.890E-09, 8.243E-10, 9.974E-12, 4.157, 3.704, 3.582, 3.649 
5.0, 1000.0, 1000000000000000.0, 115.2712, 230.538, 345.796, 461.0408, 
8.883E-09, 1.705E-08, 1.668E-09, 2.039E-11, 4.212, 3.731, 3.577, 3.648
```

Actually there are way more lines, but it's pointless to post it all. The function does some array multiplication etc. What I was hoping the code would do is: Read the first line, append the values of the columns 7-10 to the array `F[]`, call `chisqfunc` and print its result into the file `results.txt`. Afterwards proceed to the second line, append the new values to `F` etc.
But all it does is start from line 2 and do the above described procedure for line 2 and only print the value for line 2.
I suspect the problem is in the way I declared `for`.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please make sure to accurately reproduce your indentation, esp. when loops are concerned.

Comment: Why are you discarding all numbers before index 7? Just curious.

Comment: You logic is a mess I'd recommend starting over.

Comment: OP, do you have numpy installed?

Comment: @patrick Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I did not add them manually, there are needed for other parts of my program. And yes, I do have numpy installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the way you've declared your loop, indeed. In particular, you're using the enumerate function, which returns a `(index, line)` tuple. You don't capture the index separately, so you don't get the output you're looking for.

```
for line in file1:   
    F = list(map(float, map(str.strip, line.strip().split(','))))[7:11]
    ...
```

---

Here's a much better way to do this, especially if you're working with a large file of numbers: Use `numpy`.

```
In [84]: x = np.loadtxt('data.in', delimiter=',')

In [88]: F = x[:, 7:11]

In [89]: F
Out[89]: 
array([[  1.05300000e-09,   1.83900000e-09,   1.63200000e-10,
          1.95900000e-12],
       [  4.87300000e-09,   8.89000000e-09,   8.24300000e-10,
          9.97400000e-12],
       [  8.88300000e-09,   1.70500000e-08,   1.66800000e-09,
          2.03900000e-11]])
```

Here I've assumed that in the data you posted, you've manually added extra newlines which I removed to make this work. `F` contains the required data for all your rows.

Comment: For the code you wrote I'd still need some kind of (for?) loop, that will call each individual 4 digit array inside array F, use it as an argument for my chisqfunc, print the result and then go to the next 4 digit array.

Comment: A solution I thought of is to use 'for i in range()' but that will only work for this particular file with its particular number of lines. I was wondering if there was something more general.

Comment: @George You can combine that with the loop in approach 1. For approach 2, you'll still need a loop.

Comment: There's also the option of using list comprehension but it doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score -1):

`enumerate` returns value pairs: a count, followed by the elements of the given iterable.  Your `for` statement ignores the lines of the file: `line` is merely a counter from 0 to the file length in lines.

Perhaps try ...

```
for line in file1:
```

Also, if your input file has 3 lines rather than the 6 you show, please edit the posting appropriately.  Otherwise, your input line doesn't even have positions 7:11.